# Agregar Campo de busqueda en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

estoy aprendiendo javascript y me gustaria agregar un campo de busqueda que encuentre datos que se agregan previamente, que sean parecidos o iguales es lo de menos eso, solo me gustaria que haga su funcion.
estoy usando localStorage para guardar los datos, ya que aunque no son muchos si se tardaen encontrar.
muchas gracias por su apoyo

este es el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javsascript Task App</title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP 4 BOOTSWATCH LUX THEME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tasks App</a>
        
      </div>
    </nav>
    

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

              <!-- FORM TO ADD TASKS -->
              <form id="formTask">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Add A Todo" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea id="description" placeholder="Add description" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Success</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="tasks"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

este es el js

```
document.getElementById('formTask').addEventListener('submit', saveTask);
 

 function saveTask(e) {
    
    let title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    let description = document.getElementById('description').value;

    const task = {
        title,
        description
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
        let tasks = [];
        tasks.push(task);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    } else {
        let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
        tasks.push(task);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    }

    getTasks();
    document.getElementById('formTask').reset();
    e.preventDefault();
 }

  function getTasks() {
    let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    let tasksView = document.getElementById('tasks');

    tasksView.innerHTML = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        let title = tasks[i].title;
        let description = tasks[i].description;

        tasksView.innerHTML += `<div class="card mb-3">
           <div class="card-body">
            <p>${title} - ${description}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deteleTask('${title}')">
            Delete
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div>`;
    }
  }

  getTasks();

  
  function deteleTask(title) {
    let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    for(let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        if (tasks[i].title == title) {
            tasks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks)); 
    getTasks();
  }
  getTasks();
```

Answer (score 0):

A través de una función dedicada a la búsqueda, utiliza el método `filter()` que recorrerá un array y retornará un nuevo array.

Como en el localStorage tienes *title* y *description*, utiliza el método `includes()` que verificará si la string contiene otra string y retornará *true* o *false*.

Ahora la función busca y retorna title y description.

```
function busquedaTasks(busqueda) {
    const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  
    const resultado = tasks.filter(task => 
        task.title.includes(busqueda));
  
    resultado.forEach((task) => {
            console.log("title : ", task.title);
            console.log("description : ",task.description);
          });
          
  }
  busquedaTasks("test")
```

- [**developer.mozilla.org - filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [**developer.mozilla.org - includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)